# nvidia driver and cuda toolkit installed but gpu still unavailable

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I installed the Cuda compiler and Cuda toolkit on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine.

```
$nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

$ sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-cuda-toolkit is already the newest version (10.1.243-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
```

[image]

but when I try:

```
$ nvidia-smi

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Comment: Are you dual-booting with Windows **11**? If not just disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: Only ubuntu, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the recommended Nvidia drivers have been correctly installed and whenever Ubuntu is the single OS or in dual-boot with any Windows 10 or older version the easiest solution is always to **disable Secure Boot in UEFI**.